# Messages being blocked from publishing

Tags: ros, message, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running 2 nodes. One is polar_scan_matcher and the other one is my own node that publishes scan messages. Something is wrong somewhere because when the 2 nodes run at the same time, the publisher of the scan messages is being block as I received an error saying
"WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?" when I run "rostopic echo -c /scan"

As I run "rostopic list", I got these topics:/clock, /goal, /imu, /initialpose, /pose,/pose2D,/rosout, /rosout_agg,/scan,/tf.

What could be the possible culprit? How do I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12083/messages-being-blocked-from-publishing/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've somehow set the "[use_sim_time](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic)" parameter to true, but you don't have a clock source (ie: [rosbag play --clock](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play) or some other source, like Gazebo).

Since you're using tf, [WallTime](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Time#Wall_Time) isn't an option.

You can check the status of the use_sim_time parameter by using [rosparam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam#rosparam_command-line_tool).

```
rosparam get use_sim_time
```

And if it is set somehow, you can reverse it by running:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time false
```

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
You're right..I've just changed the value in the launch file and that works..Thanks anyway.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-24**:
Should I run/include this on in the launch file or running as a command? I've tried as a command, still not working..

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-08-29**:
Just one small addition because it confused one of my contacts:
***If you use Gazebo this does not apply to you***. Gazebo publishes the /clock topic for you.

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-08**:
@Chad Rockey I have a question to your recommendation with the flaf of the `use_sim_time`. In my launch file first I've set this to true, because I get the message about `TF_OLD_DATA` while playing my recorded `bag file`. But now I try to use a node and it seems, that the topics is published, but no messages are received (simulated time is active)